# MongoDB/React Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I am following this MERN tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngc9gnGgUdA
Around @18:00 is where I am having problems.  After some research I think some of the code in the video is outdated and I am doing my best to get this to work!  This is my *current* error: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';

import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js';


const app = express();

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);
 

app.use(bodyParser.json( { limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { limit: "30mb", extended: true}));

app.use(cors());

const CONNECTION_URL = 'mongodb+srv://test:test123@cluster0.mql8u.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;


mongoose.createConnection(CONNECTION_URL).asPromise();

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL)
.then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on port: ${PORT}` )))
.catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

I **SUPER** appreciate any and all help. If anyone can point me in the direction of a better tutorial that would be amazing! I am a novice code, I finished a virtual coding bootcamp recently, but I need to make some real apps.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First I would check and see if you already have something running on port 5000, to confirm, I would run `npx kill-port 5000`, then try to run port 5000 again to see if that port is now free after killing it via the previously noted command...

Answer (score 0):

BEFORE:
Run `npm start` in the terminal and check the output to see if the terminal print something like `server.js nodemon src/server.js`.

REASON:
If you do then your scripts are calling `server.js` twice, which is causing this Error.

FIX:
I had the same issue and fixed it by fixing my `package.json` in root folder and also the `package.json` in the server folder.

AFTER:
you should see the terminal print `nodemon src/server.js` when you run your script.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ah. My problem was related to [EternalBlew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75255708/4502060). I was asking the application to listen twice.

```
import application from "./app";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import env from "./util/validEnv";


const port = env.PORT;

console.log(env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING)
mongoose.connect(env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING,)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Mongoose connected");
          application.listen(port, () => {
            console.log("Server running on port " + port);
          });
        })
        .catch(console.error);

application.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server running from port: " + port)
});
```

Deleting the second application.listen block solved the problem.